# Div height fill container with margin

Tags: html, css

Take a look at my html and css:

```
html , body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;    
}

.wrapper {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content {  
    margin: 10px auto 20px auto;
    width: 724px;
    border: black 1px solid;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My wrapper div on default take window width and window height as its size. I want my content div always fill wrapper height and keep its margin, the problem is I can't set content div's height = 100% because it has margin, and will make wrapper div overflow. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/trongcuong1710/T7D32/) is my jsfiddle

**Edit**

Example to clarify the question:

Assume that `div.wrapper`'s height = 200px

`div.content`'s height will be 200 - (10 + 20) = 170px

I know I can do this by jquery but I want to find a solution with html/css

**Note:** `div.wrapper`'s height depend on user screen resolution.

**SOLVE**

Thanks for your guys attention! I really appreciate it. And I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165125/make-two-css-elements-fill-their-container-side-by-side-with-margin) by using css3 `calc` function. I think this information will helpful to you.

Comment: sorry i don't really get your question, can't you just remove the margin?

Comment: I want to keep the margin. That's why I can't set `content div`'s height = 100%. And about the question. Let me clarify it by example. Assume that `wrapper div`'s height = 200px, so `content div`'s height = 200 - (10 + 20) = 170px. I can do it by jquery on page load but I want to achieve it by pure html/css

Comment: have you tried floating the div so that it fills in its parent element?

Comment: @oshikryu can you be more specific?

Comment: something like div.content{ float:left; }. That should fill the parent class if you don't specify a width. Then you can add margins

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood, I want to fill the height, not the width

Comment: There is a css proeprty call Border-Box which solves your issue, but for some reason i can't apply to your jsfiddle page.
ref 1: http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/box_sizing/
ref 2: http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/T7D32/9/

**updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/T7D32/13/**

**i have done some minor changes in your css code here is**

```
html , body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;    
}

.wrapper {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:10px 0 20px 0;
}

.content {  
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 724px;
    border: black 1px solid;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

it will work let me know if you have any problem

Comment: There's one problem. When you set `height: 100%`, content div overflow and I don't want that behavior. I want it fit inside parent without overflow

Comment: @DoanCuong because you are using `border` for this you can use `border-box` property and it will work

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/T7D32/11/).

The HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
html , body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;    
}

.wrapper {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(193, 112, 39) 0%, rgb(243, 141, 49) 20%, rgb(203, 119, 41) 99%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content {  
    margin: 10px auto 20px auto;
    width: 724px;
    border: black 1px solid;
    height:inherit;
    overflow:auto;
    background:blue;
    width:auto;
}
```

The issue was in the content class. If you want the content div wrap the height of wrapper div, a `height:inherit;` has to be specified which inherits the height of its parent div.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

change the .content class css like this, your problem will be solved.

```
.content {  
    margin: 10px auto 20px auto;
    width: 724px;
    border: black 1px solid;
     overflow: auto;
    height: 100%
}
```